# How do i get rid of these circles appearing on the background I created while using emit?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been using blender render just to make a new background for my computer, and it involves 3 planes which can all be seen: The background is one, and the 3 is one, and the ring around the 3 is one. I messed with the emit on the 3 and the ring (it's the same material for both) and the more light they emit, the more visible these spots are. Anyone know what to fix? I have indirect lighting turned on with 2 passes allowed it that matters. [image: This is the final image that renders, sorry for low quality]

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out what was wrong, the 3 and the ring were too close to the background. This appears to be "Z Fighting."